# Overlapping banner ([Sign up] and [Terms of Service]) for anonymous user

Tags: bug, design

Reproduce:

- Open private/anonymous tab
- Go to [Display Progress Bar at the Time of Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1000000)

Result:

[image]

You can see that the two banners at the bottom of the page overlaps, <s>which saves some horizontal page space</s>.

Clicking the lower [x] gives:

[image]

Only after that the [Email sign up] button is displayed.

---

By the way, the issue is not present in other sites, as other sites use the <s>huge</s> banner for [Sign up] instead.

[image]

Comment: Though qutebrowser is not one of the [supported browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/369403), this issue is easily reproduced in supported browsers.